# Should we have a software-recommendation tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

Are software-recommendation questions on topic?

#### Examples

1. [What is the best way to access a DRM ridden flash sites like Hulu or YouTube?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1461/86)
2. [What is the most practical OS to install long term?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1443/86) (closed)
3. [Has anyone got a Text to Speech engine installed?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1015/86)

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

Software recommendation questions can provide a good reference for people looking for software for certain situations. They will take a lot of moderating to prevent them getting subjective.

### Other SE sites

Some other SE sites have [software-recommendation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation)

#### Ask Ubuntu

[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) have a [software-recommendation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation). It is tightly regulated, as per their meta discussions.

Answer (score 4):

## The tag will stay, unless it becomes a problem.

> software that runs on the Raspberry Pi

According to our [faq](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq) any question about software that runs on the Raspberry Pi is on-topic. This means that recommendations about software is on-topic, for now.

Currently all of the questions tagged [software-recommendation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) are of high enough quality. As long as this tag doesn't become a cesspit then it will be allowed to say.

Comment: I've un-deleted this because I agree (I hope you don't mind).